# update Spring BOOT-INF/lib jars

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, package

I am trying to update a jar in `rest-xxxx.jar`, this rest jar is basically a SpringBoot Jar and has the folder structure of `BOOT-INF/lib/<dependencies.jars>` when you unpack it.

Now I want to replace a dependency jar within this `rest-xxxx.jar`, so I used the command:

```
jar uf rest-xxxx.jar BOOT-INF/lib/new-version-jar-same-name.jar
```

How ever I got errors during booting process:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'BOOT-INF/lib/new-version-jar-same-name.jar'. It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file

I noticed that there's a `0` option for jar command to avoid compression, so I did:

```
jar u0f rest-xxxx.jar BOOT-INF/lib/new-version-jar-same-name.jar
```

But then I got a similar compression issue like below:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'BOOT-INF/lib/new-version-jar-same-name.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'. It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file

What should I do when I need to replace the dependency jars within a given springboot jar?

**please note:** I understand the best practise is to build from updated pom.xml, the limitations we have is that we cannot get the right version source code at the moment, hence we are trying to patch the existing springboot jar instead of rebuilding it.

Comment: I think the `metron-rest-xxxx.jar` JAR itself must be uncompressed.

Comment: What I am trying to do is update what's inside the `metron-rest-xxx.jar`, so can't uncompress this jar. I just change the `metron-rest-xxx.jar` to `rest-xxxx.jar` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Why can't you just update the dependencies in the pom.xml and rebuild the Spring Boot application?

Comment: this is worst practice.

Comment: *What should I do when I need to replace the dependencies with a given springboot jar?* I would update the dependencies in the build.gradle/pom.xml of the project (i.e. in the sources), recompile and reexecute all the unit and integration tests to make sure the new dependency doesn't break anything, and use the jar produced by the official, carefully crafted build procedure of the project.

Comment: guys, I understanding this will be way easier if I could rebuild from src code and put thing into maven pom.xml. But the problem I have is that now I only have a jar file that I need to patch, so you could talk about best practise but I need to patch this jar.

Comment: I do want to chase up the src code with correct changesets but unfortunately I can't have it at the moment, that is why I need to patch it instead of rebuilding it. Can we focus on the scenario when we need to patch this?

Comment: I would try this: unjar the "new" jar -> re-jar it without compression -> update it (without compression) inside the Spring Boot app JAR.

Comment: Tried it but not working same error

Comment: You simply cannot do this (or is very hard to do) because the packing format of Springboot is different. If you open up the jar in text editor you will see meta data on top and all libs in binary format inline. So it will be very hard to repackage it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the jar command to decompress the jar package, replace the jar package outside the compressed package, and compress it.

https://www.programmersought.com/article/48535890080/

Answer (score 0):

My initial answer was deleted, so I'm following recommendations and updating my answer.

Regarding comments, sometimes it's faster to cut corners and just patch jar/zip file directly instead of rebuilding the whole thing that can take a lot of time on large projects.

There is nothing wrong with the Spring Boot file layout unless jar names and compression methods are retained, the nested .jars are only "indexed" by their names, and OP means replacing .jar with the same name.

I've faced the very same question as OP and haven't found a solution, so this is my attempt to solve it with utility https://github.com/denizk0/cpzip

This utility 1. Updates a file in the zip/jar, if it's a nested archive, it's expanded to a temp file, then GOTO 1. Nesting may be of any depth. Eventually, all nested archives are wrapped back together, temp files are cleaned. Compression methods are preserved.

Here's an example:

`cpzip ~/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.9/joda-time-2.9.9.jar camunda-bpm-run-7.16.0.zip internal/camunda-bpm-run-core.jar/BOOT-INF/lib -v`

will copy or replace `joda-time-2.9.9.jar` from local maven repo in `camunda-bpm-run-7.16.0.zip` from current directory in nested `internal/camunda-bpm-run-core.jar`

PS: It is even possible to replace .js files in webjars